# Android - Changing an alpha value of a LayerDrawable item , triggered by onClick event

Tags: android, layer

a newbie question.

I'm trying to change an `alpha value` of a `bitmap item` inside a `layer-list`.

my `drawable xml` is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/img_btn" android:gravity="center"/>
    </item>
    <item>
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/image_frame" android:gravity="center"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

my `MainActivity` is as follows:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        MainApp.show(this);
        addListeners();
        changeAlpha(128);
    }

    private void changeAlpha(int opc){
        ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_A);
        LayerDrawable layer = (LayerDrawable) img.getDrawable();
        BitmapDrawable bg = (BitmapDrawable) layer.getDrawable(0);
        bg.setAlpha(opc);
    }

    private void addListeners() {
        ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_A);

        View.OnClickListener imageAClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                changeAlpha(255);
            }
        };

        img.setOnClickListener(imageAClickListener);
    }

    public void onBackPressed() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage(Definitions.CONFIRM_EXIT)
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton(Definitions.YES, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        MainActivity.this.finish();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(Definitions.NO, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }
}
```

the first call to `changeAlpha` (from `onCreate`) works just fine, but when I call the method from the `click` event it does nothing (without failing)

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try adding

```
img.invalidate();
```

to last line of your changeAlpha() method.

Comment: cool! I hope you understand what the problem was. A repaint was needed. When you set it in onCreate, the image is automatically rendered first time. But later when you modify it you have to have it repainted. Classic java has a nice methode called repaint().  Android takes a more passive approach i guess :P :P :P

Comment: Thanks again for elaborating, I kind'a guessed it was the issue.

Comment: I would appreciate if you could look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/8630365/1115237

Answer (score 2):

in some case,you should call`img.setImageDrawable(layer)`,it will cause repain.